# How to Verify each line of the function with negative values using Jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a function which returns nothing. How can I write the Jest test cases for negative scenarios.

```js
setTimeIntervalTrackConfiguration(
    trackIntervalConfiguration: BellIntervalData[],
  ): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < trackIntervalConfiguration.length; i) {
      const config = trackIntervalConfiguration[i]
      const url = config.track.url
      const fileDescriptor = Number(url)
      if (!Number.isNaN(fileDescriptor)) {
        config.track.url = super.resolveAsset(fileDescriptor).uri
      }
    }
    this.nativePlayer.setTimeIntervalTrackConfiguration(
      trackIntervalConfiguration,
    )
  }
```

1. How to Verify the number of times for loop execution.
2. Other negative scenarios.

Comment: Mock the passed object and put jest.fn() into the getters